# cracking SHA256 if you think you know its original value but don't know which is it

Tags: hash-functions

I have a hash and what I think is its original value

```
DRMSoftwareRadio-MERLIN-00000218
20030130
Frank Garnier
Frank.Garnier@rnw.nl
Witte Kruislaan 55
Hilversum
1217AM
Netherlands
a9ba81b656e632dfdeaa2889c7a1be385cf8d351e194dedb1813a00b7d7c2c55
99b9e76825dc15ca02319b9ac513e84e48a38364c218918403c224bc4ff57e48
fde9381908812fb42badd491f87f7517c66cdfd6dabad086fb4ed21448123e8e
92a8c2ae5a1e245283cc1ac66b3e0f9f2e855993fe082a5a5949cfdb4e2e78ea
5b996cbd1bfe938c28ab4b5d0273322d47ccf4c526756184175cc35ec9be6e25
5c909807d11e6b59bff2599347f7b09b49de6e46d8c1561cec06435b5787bd3f
fbefca813967061dad73f65918169a039d3d41fa315ba1f04d50276de58f8c17
9e80a9323c238c6359f7cbb95d1a18edaab116e9178a6c88a000179dac5c41d2
```

I know this hash is some of this values above
and think that `20030130` should belong to`99b9e76825dc15ca02319b9ac513e84e48a38364c218918403c224bc4ff57e48`

so how can I figure out if `20030130` (because there are only numbers and its short) belongs to any of this hashes and possibly hash it in such a way I get one of this hashes for it

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just plug it in any SHA256 hash-algorithm calculator and see! You can [do this online](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html) or use a simple Python module like [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) to hash things on your own.

Using both the online program and a simple python3 script I wrote, `20030130` doesn't match any of the hashes listed (instead producing the hash `8fbaf5a8fedcebe1214b6fd23bec5db357ba4f6323630a1d59ffe86d948f0b81`). There is a good chance a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) could be being used, which means the hashes would have a different word prepended that makes cracking a hash more difficult.

Comment: but its a very old program: http://www.winradio.com/software/drm_software_radio_2.0.38.zip, I don't think they used salt in 2004
also how can I figure what hash algo is used
here is the function that should calculate it: https://pastebin.com/EHq1fFJr

Comment: Salts have been used since before the 1980s. If your question is "how do I know what hash algorithm this is?" that's an entirely different question and you should update your question accordingly. What hash algorithms have you tried?

Comment: SHA512, SHA384, SHA1, MD5

after using SND Reverser tool said they are used